# Python install uninstall easy_install

Tags: python, easy-install

I have two versions of python on my mac:

One preinstalled by Apple in `/usr/bin`

One from python.org in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6`

easy_install always installs to `/usr/bin` for some ununderstanable reason

So I explicitly now install easy_install in:

```
sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg --install-dir=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

Now I want to easy_install pip AND ....:

```
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 0.8
Processing pip-0.8-py2.6.egg
pip 0.8 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
error: /usr/local/bin/pip: Permission denied
```

My path and pythonpath:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages"
export PYTHONPATH
```

- One more PYTHONPATH where I keep modules I wrote

Sorry I really dont get it.

What am I doing wrong.

I just want to install modules regularly in the Framework Python directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what state your installation is in based on the information supplied.  `/usr/local/bin` is the default installation location for the Apple-supplied `/usr/bin/easy_install` so, most likely, you are somehow invoking that instead of the `easy_install` that should have been installed by running the `sh setuptools...` script. There is no need to use the `--install-dir` param to setuptools nor to set `PYTHONPATH` to point to the framework site-packages directory; that happens automatically. And you should not modify the `PATH` variable twice, just use the first PATH and export.

Starting from a newly-installed Python 2.6.5 from the python.org installer and a new terminal session, here's the whole sequence:

```
$ curl -O http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  325k  100  325k    0     0   125k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  136k
$ PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:${PATH}"
$ export PATH
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
$ which python2.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
$ python2.6 -c "import sys;print(sys.version_info)"
(2, 6, 5, 'final', 0)
$ sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg 
Processing setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
Copying setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages
Adding setuptools 0.6c11 to easy-install.pth file
Installing easy_install script to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin
Installing easy_install-2.6 script to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin
Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
$ which easy_install
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/easy_install
$ easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Reading http://pip.openplans.org
Best match: pip 0.8
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-0.8.tar.gz#md5=468d9adc309f33ad51cee38f0d455429
Processing pip-0.8.tar.gz
Running pip-0.8/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/Ux/UxzFPTCnF3esOnKQ1d3bbE+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-JU05mJ/pip-0.8/egg-dist-tmp-zwrzwI
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.txt' found under directory 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build/_sources'
Adding pip 0.8 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin
Installing pip-2.6 script to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin
Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.8-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
$ pip --version
pip 0.8 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.8-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)
```

Comment: Thanks again! I learned so  much from your last answer! How can i get a clean blade again. How can I uninstall everything? Sitepackages and python? So nothing is left that could potentially be wrong!

Comment: just read the whole sequence: 

1. How can this command: sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg install it to Framework instead of usr/bin. If I do the exact same it writes it to usr/bin

2. which easy_install: Thanks for life for that!!!

Comment: To remove the python.org 2.6 to start over:
`sudo rm -r /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6`
That's all on one line. Type carefully!  The `sh setuptools...` script uses whichever `python2.6` command is found first on your shell `PATH`.  That should be the one in the frameworks `bin` directory.

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall django package.

First you have to run this command,

$ easy_install -m [PACKAGE]

This command will remove all dependencies of package. then remove egg file of that package.

$ rm -rf .../python2.X/site-packages/[PACKAGE].egg

Comment: OSX: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/