# Unable to install pip: Permission denied error

Tags: python, easy-install, egg, pypi

I am trying to install pip but currently unable to.
I navigate to the pip folder and

```
python setup.py install
```

Everything seems to go fine until the very end:

```
Extracting pip-0.8.2-py2.6.egg to /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
Adding pip 0.8.2 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
error: /usr/local/bin/pip: Permission denied
```

I've also tried `easy_install .` and attempted to refer to the related thread with no luck: [Python install uninstall easy_install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582715/python-install-uninstall-easy-install)

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the command as a super user? (sudo python setup.py install)?

Comment: `python setup.py config --prefix=/path/to/directory/you/have/write/permissions/ && python setup.py install` may help

Comment: Sudo WORKED! :)  Resubmit as an answer and so I can mark it.  (Is that something people do on StackOverflow?) Thanks!

Comment: In my case I simply do `python3 setup.py install --prefix=~/.local/` which install it in `~/.local/bin/` (ensure set `~/.local/bin` in `$PATH` too), no need install in `/usr/local/bin/` without good reason.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like you're on an Linux/Unix box and you're not root ... which means you don't have *permission* to put things in `/usr/local/bin` (or a lot of other places).

**Update for comments:**

Since OS X is (under the hood) FreeBSD Unix, there is still the basic concept of 'root'. Your admin account is *capable* of doing root-type things, but it doesn't automatically escalate privileges (which is a Good Thing). The command you are looking for is `sudo`, which provides temporary root privileges. To do it for a single command (the most normal case), simply prefix the command with `sudo`, e.g. `sudo python setup.py install`. You will probably be prompted to supply your password again (not *root*'s password, but your own) and then the command will be executed. `sudo` will only prompt you the first time (or every N minutes) for a password.

I noted [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA25121) that in 10.5 and later, `sudo` will only work if your admin account has a password. If it doesn't, then you will have to set one before this will work.

If you have a whole bunch of stuff you need to do as root, try `sudo /bin/bash` (or you shell of choice), which will give you a new shell (as a child process of the other shell) which has *full root privileges*. **Note Well:** if you are not use to living at a root-prompt, this is not a great idea. One slip of the keyboard and you can nail your system to the outhouse wall. So be careful out there!

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X, on my admin account.  Thoughts?

Comment: `sudo /bin/bash` don't do that. Just do `sudo su`

Comment: @Falmarri: does that mean there is no `/bin/bash` on OS X? Or that the shell exists and that `sudo` doesn't work with it?

Comment: @Peter: Oh, I don't have a mac so I have no idea. I'm just saying `sudo su` is the more standard way of doing it.

Comment: @Falmarri: It's not standard if you're such an old fart you didn't learn about `sudo` until it had been out for about 10 years! :-) I'd never seen `sudo su` before your post, but it makes perfect sense. I was curious and tried `su`, `sudo su`, and `sudo /bin/bash`, each followed by `env > /tmp/env.X`. Each of them produces a different set of environment variables/values in env.su, env.sudo.su, and env.sudo.bash -- that looks like a good way to get really subtle, hard-to-find bugs/variances ... sigh.

Comment: If you want to keep your user environment settings you can do `sudo su -`