# Python & BeautifulSoup Setup Not Working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Cannot install BeautifulSoup on my computer and it continues to tell me that I don't have writable access? See below:

```
Last login: Fri Jun 26 14:08:26 on ttys000
Britneys-MacBook-Air:~ Pryde$ pip install requests
-bash: pip: command not found
Britneys-MacBook-Air:~ Pryde$ easy_install requests
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-19650.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. -Thanks!

Comment: You are installing `requests`, not BeautifulSoup, there.

Comment: [Similar issue about installing Python libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359870/unable-to-install-pip-permission-denied-error)

Answer (score 1):

When using pip install on a Mac, you need to run that command as sudo (a *temporary admin escalation* if you want a really bad explanation of what sudo does - it will prompt you for your password).

```
sudo pip install requests
```

That will solve your writeable access.  However as another poster mentioned, you are dealing with requests, not BeautifulSoup.  Same applies re sudo.

**pip list** and other non-install/modifying pip subcommands can run just fine without sudo.

**update: you don't seem to have pip installed yet.**  My bad, I didn't catch that because you pasted in the pip install, got an error, but then tried **easy install** and the bulk of the message concerns easy install.

This link explains how to install pip.  [install pip on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x).  Notice the **sudo** again.  Once that has worked, you can re-try your first **sudo pip install requests**.

You probably want to do that, because **pip** seems generally more clever than just **easy install** by itself.

Comment: I've tried that too and get this:

Comment: Britneys-MacBook-Air:Downloads Pryde$ sudo pip install requests
    Password:
    sudo: pip: command not found
    Britneys-MacBook-Air:Downloads Pryde$

Comment: is your user with admin rights on that Mac?  What does **sudo -s** by itself do?