# Uninstall Easy_Install

Tags: python, easy-install

So I installed Python 2.7.1 *from source* on a server using [stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/).  I have been careless in the past, and I am trying to keep organized when dealing with source installs.  So, enter stow.  Now I installed easy_install with `wget` and running the `ez_setup.py` script.  Lo and behold, in my infinite wisdom/carelessness, I forgot to stow it properly.

1. How do I uninstall ez_setup and start from scratch?  I have seen a couple of people ask on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582715/python-install-uninstall-easy-install) and other places on the web, but there is no clear answer.  Do I just uninstall the .egg, the .pth file, and be done with it?
2. Does this matter? I had adjusted my `PATH` variable anyway, plus I do not even have su access on this box. I installed into my own Python install, already configured with stow.

Answer (score 6):

Go to your "site-packages" directory (look at your `sys.path`) and then run:

```
rm -rf setuptools-*.egg pkg_resources.py easy_install.py setuptools/ setuptools-*.egg-info/
```

And delete the `easy_install` binary as well. I came up with these instructions when writing [FAQ for PyPM](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/faq.html#what-if-i-have-setuptools-installed).

Comment: @Srihdar Sounds cool.  I will check it out when I get back home.